# How to calculate total price after discount input

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Calculate total price after discount input** OnChange not working

```js
function CalcDiscount()
{
 var qty = document.getElementById("ticket-count").innerText;
 var value = document.getElementById("item-price").innerText;
 var discount = document.getElementById("discount").value;
 var total =  value * qty;
 var gtotal =  total - discount;
 //document.getElementById("total-price").value = gtotal; 
 $("#total-price").val(gtotal);
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Ticket Fare: <span id="item-price" class="item-price">450</span><br />
Ticket Number:<span class="ticket-count" id="ticket-count" > 5</span><br />

Discount: <input class="discount" id="discount" name="discount" type="text" onkeyup="CalcDiscount();"> <br /><br />
Total: <input class="total-price" id="total-price" name="totalprice" type="text" >
```

Comment: Your code works when I try it. I type `10` into Discount and press Enter and it puts `2240` in Total.

Comment: You know that `onchange` is only triggered when you leave the input field after changing it, right? Not after every keystroke. For that, use `onkeyup`.

Comment: Thanks For the suggestion it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your values from strings to numbers.

Try this:

```
function CalcDiscount()
{
    var qty = parseInt(document.getElementById("ticket-count").innerText);
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("item-price").innerText);
    var discount = parseInt(document.getElementById("discount").value);
    var total =  value * qty;
    var gtotal =  total - discount;
    //document.getElementById("total-price").value = gtotal;    
    $("#total-price").val(gtotal);
}
```

Comment: Converting the strings to numbers is needed only if you were adding.  (But it's not a bad policy to do so regardless.)

Comment: It also work but the problem is after changing it to int when you delete the discount then total price return null value. SO `onkeyup` is good solution